# Curse word in link

Tags: discussion

I just answered a question in which I wanted to offer the site "http://f**ingswiftblocksyntax.com" as a possible resource because a user was not familiar with the subject.

I feel that this site is absolutely great for explaining quickly what a closure is, but on the stack exchange meta there are people who strongly dislike the practice of cursing on stack overflow (let alone in real life) (@Jeff Atwood on meta).

Should I have not posted the link, even though it is a nice site?

EDIT: I have decided to just hide the link from view

Comment: The closely-related http://fuckingblocksyntax.com has a curse-free synonym http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com You could possibly ask the owner to provide such an alias via a GitHub issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not your fault that the URL is what it is. You have a couple options if you don't want to show the URL though:

- Find another resource to link. Somewhere else in the wide open internet, this data exists. Use that link instead.
- Use anchor text so that the user doesn't see the URL in the post. `[Swift Closures and Functions](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/)` will show as [Swift Closures and Functions](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/). Another option is to use the `Hyperlink` button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) after selecting text and paste the link. It makes the Markdown slightly different but still utilizes the anchor text instead of showing the URL directly.

In either case, you should also pull in relevant information from that link to your answer (and attribute the website using one of the options from above).